# why FileOutputStream writes to different positions on disk?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

i am using FileOutputStream to write my content to a file "sample.txt" on a android device SD card

but every time i try to write the content, FileOutputStream writes it on a different position on disk.

i have check the start position of the file "sample.txt", and every time it increases 512 byte!

what should i do?

Answer (score 5):

If you're *overwriting* the file, then that's just the file system doing its thing, nothing to do with `FileOutputStream`. It's not unusual for flash-memory-based file systems to avoid reusing the same part of the device over and over, because flash has a limited number of write/erase cycles, so flash-memory file systems try to spread the writes over the entire device, reusing previously-used areas only when they're the oldest available. It's fine and there's nothing you need to do about it, the file system sorts it out.

If you're *appending* to the file, e.g. using one of the [constructors that allows appending](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean)), e.g.:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("sample.txt", true); // true = append
```

...then the file is growing, because that's what you're asking it to do. If that's not what you want, use one of the other constructors or pass `false` for the `append` argument.